# Oracle Accessing Data from Two Databases Transparently

Tags: oracle, database-design, high-availability, vpd

Our Oracle version is 19c

We have a need to split our data into two separate databases.

Most recent data will go into DB_1.
Older data will go into DB_2.

We do have Webserver tier.

One options is to have views as follows

```
  CREATE VIEW all_cust as
    SELECT * FROM customer@DB_1 where ( date within 1 months )
       union
    SELECT * from customer@DB_2 where ( date > 1 months )
```

But this will require massive changes to application - because all accesses to CUSTOMER will need to be changed to ALL_CUST.

Can the above setup be configured so that it is completely transparent to application ?

Can VPD be a solution to this ?

Comment: VPD is access control. It modifies SQL predicates (the `where` clause) transparently to restrict access to data at the row level. It will not help with your current problem. If you split into two databases I don't see a way around modifying your source: your app will presumably still need to make changes to the `customer` table data in DB_1, so the meaning of `customer` would appear to be conditional on whether you're performing DML operations or selecting for reports - you won't be able to use it for both purposes because the table and the view can't share the same name.

Comment: We can handle DML by creating an INSTEAD OF trigger on the CUST_ALL view. The trigger logic will send update to either DB_1 or DB_2 - depending upon whether the recent data needs to be modified or older.

Comment: If that allows you to change the table name so the view can use `customer` then it sounds like you've answered your own question, assuming there are no source code implications for changing the table name and replacing it with the view.

Comment: Can we instead have a PUBLIC SYNONYM as follows : CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM CUSTOMER as SCHEMA.ALL_CUST. This way the change will be totally transparent to application. Will this work ?

Comment: This seems like a solution which hasn’t been thought through, will the application know how old the data it needs to use is? You’ll always be querying both databases but will need one of them to handle the query so data will need to move from one to the other before it’s allowed to go to the application. Distributed queries classically become difficult to optimize so you might fall into weird issues there anyway. What are you really trying to do? Usually people use partitioning to archive old data